# Trills in Bach with historical information

Tags: j-s-bach, ornaments

This is an old question, but I have issues with playing the tr's in Bach's wtc. His autograph instruction for embellishments (he gave to his son) indicated a trillo to be played without the ending mordent. In his fugue 7 (d minor) he uses the tr's for notes, and then be uses a trillo und mordent somewhere else. Does he mean the tr's to be played like the trillo he described without the ending mordent?

Comment: Are you talking about WTC I-6 BWV 851? We do have a question on the trills here: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15205/trill-in-bach-fugue-wtc-1-bwv-851. As a rule, when Bach needs a turned trill, he specifies it; regular trills aren't turned at the end. However, there is an element of _a piacere_ in ornamentation, even in Bach, so you do have some leeway in how to play the trills, provided you don't break the character of the piece.

Comment: Great to know, I am playing the trills unturned now. Yes sorry I mean number 6 indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Several of the Alfred Masterwork Editions of Bach's piano music have excellent explanations of many of these matters and even have them notated above each symbol: [WTC Book 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0882841203)